# TLE on counting the number of elements within the specified ranges in a list

Tags: python, list, performance, optimization

There is an unsorted list `a` and a list of ranges like `ranges = [(10, 20), (30, 50), (15, 35) ...]`. The maximum value in `a` is `uint64_t`. The goal is to count the number of elements for each range. The normal solution is quite intuitive, just count the elements within the range and print the result. But the question is from a Online Judge. I tired sereval solutions, but for each of them, OJ gave a Time Limit Exceeded.

The max length of `a` is 10,000,000, the max length of `ranges` is 1,000,000.

The test list `a` with 10 million random numbers and the `ranges` with 1 million pair of ranges:

```
import numpy as np

a = list(np.random.randint(low=1, high=0x7fffffffffffffff, size=10_000_000))

ranges = []
for _ in range(1_000_000):
    x, y = np.random.randint(low=1, high=0x7fffffffffffffff, size=2)
    ranges.append((x, y) if x < y else (y, x))
```

The first solution is:

```
import bisect

a.sort()

low_d = {}
up_d = {}

def count(r):
    low, up = r

    if low not in low_d:
        l = bisect.bisect_left(a, low)
        low_d[low] = l
    else:
        l = low_d[low]

    if up not in up_d:
        u = bisect.bisect_right(a, up, lo=l)
        up_d[up] = u
    else:
        u = up_d[up]

    return u - l

result = [*map(count, ranges)]
```

The disadvantage is pretty obvious that the `sort()` is very time consuming when `a` is very large.

> The original second solution is much slower than the above solution.
>
> Abandoned.

Both solutions resulted in TLE errors. The OJ I used is like a black box which I don't know the test examples it used to test the program.

Since the program is running on a OJ, `numpy` is not allowed to be used.

Is there any method to optimize the performance?

Comment: You could also sort ranges instead of array, e.g. by start. And maybe once more by end.

Comment: @keiv.fly I was enlightened by you to merge the start list and the end list, then sorted the merged list. For only one loop over `a`, a `dict` `d` is used to save `d[x] = (the number of elements before x, the number of elements including x)`. However, the speed is not much improved (`bisect`: ~20, this method: ~19). As the major time consuming part is `a.sort()`. Do you have further idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This C++ code runs in 1.9s compiled with `-O2` vs my best Python code 13.2s on this hardware (This is a slower hardware compared to the benchmarks in Python).

Possible improvements:

1. Upper bisect should search above lower bisect
2. Use pre-calculated bisect values like in python code
3. Implement Unisort algorithm from [Unisort: an Algorithm to Sort Uniformly Distributed Numbers in O(n) Time. R.T. Ionescu 2013](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319980213_Unisort_an_Algorithm_to_Sort_Uniformly_Distributed_Numbers_in_On_Time)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int tdiff(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> _end) {
    int result;
    result = (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(_end - start)).count();
    return result; 
}

int main() 
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int64_t> dis(1, 0x7fffffffffffffff);

    #define A_SIZE 10000000
    #define R_SIZE 1000000
    std::vector<int64_t> a(A_SIZE);
    int a_size = A_SIZE;
    int r_size = R_SIZE;
    for (int i=0; i<a_size; i++){
        a[i] = dis(gen);
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int64_t>> ranges1(R_SIZE, std::vector<int64_t>(2));

    int64_t x,y;
    for (int i=0; i<ranges1.size(); i++){
        x = dis(gen);
        y = dis(gen);
        if (x < y){
            ranges1[i] = {x,y};
        }else{
            ranges1[i] = {y,x};
        }
    }
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, _end;

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::vector<int64_t> counts(A_SIZE);
    std::vector<int64_t>::iterator l;
    std::vector<int64_t>::iterator u;
    for (int i=0; i<r_size; i++){
        l = std::lower_bound(a.begin(),a.end(),ranges1[i][0]);
        u = std::upper_bound(a.begin(),a.end(),ranges1[i][1]);
        counts[i] = (int64_t)std::distance(l,u);
    }
    _end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << tdiff(start, _end) << "\n";

    std::cout << counts[0] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to reduce the time from 13.1s to 11.2s on my machine

My final code:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
def f0_4(a, ranges, n_pre_b):
    a.sort()
    blen = [x*len(a)//n_pre_b for x in range(n_pre_b)]
    b1 = [a[i] for i in blen]
    blen.append(len(a))
    b1.append(a[-1])
    res = []
    for low, up in ranges: 
        low_pre_b_i = bisect_left(b1,low)
        lo = blen[low_pre_b_i-1]
        hi = blen[low_pre_b_i]
        l = bisect_left(a, low, lo=lo, hi=hi)
        high_pre_b_i = bisect_left(b1,up)
        lo = blen[high_pre_b_i-1]
        hi = blen[high_pre_b_i]
        if l > lo:
            res.append(bisect_right(a, up, lo=l, hi=hi)-l)
        else:
            res.append(bisect_right(a, up, lo=lo, hi=hi)-l)

    return res
res = f0_4(a,ranges,16384)
```

What and why:

1. I removed the function call "count", because every call is an overhead in python
2. I removed the caching of values for bisect, because the probability of having the same bisect values is small. Tests showed that it is faster without caching
3. I precalculated some ranges for the `a` list. 16384 precalculated values was optimal. This gave the biggest boost to speed
4. I replaced `bisect.bisect_left` with `bisect_left` by changing the imports. Same for `bisect_right`. Dot calls have overhead in python

What I would have done but it was against the rules (correct me if I am wrong. The methods below could increase speed up to 100 times):

1. Use numpy arrays instead of python lists. Sorting is 10 times faster. Allows to use fast numba and cython code. Element access is faster
2. Use a special sort algorithm for uniformly distributed interger numbers in cython or numba. Potentially could improve sorting 100 times from the original. This sorting is linear to array size. That is not possible with general sorting algorithms, which python lists and numpy arrays use
3. Use numpy.searchsorted() instead of bisect
4. Convert all for loops to numba or cython code. Loops are very inefficient in python

I could probably write C++ code that will be about 100 times faster, by implementing all of the above. In my small C++ experience it was always faster than any optimization of cython or numpy. But C++ is a different question.

What I have tried and it was worse:

1. Sorting the ranges and not sorting `a`. The time increased 4 times compared to the question asker's version. Most likely due to much higher complexity of the code
2. Guessing the bisection by dividing the number by the maximum number. And then search with bisection in the vicinity. Was faster than the asker's version but slower than the final version with precalculated intervals.
3. Using dictionaries instead of lists. Was worse

Line profiler of the code:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                            def f0_4(a, ranges, n_pre_b):
     2         1    6465309.0 6465309.0     39.8      a.sort()
     3         1       3088.0    3088.0      0.0      blen = [x*len(a)//n_pre_b for x in range(n_pre_b)]
     4         1       4661.0    4661.0      0.0      b1 = [a[i] for i in blen]
     5         1          4.0       4.0      0.0      blen.append(len(a))
     6         1          1.0       1.0      0.0      b1.append(a[-1])
     7         1          1.0       1.0      0.0      res = []
     8   1000001     540421.0       0.5      3.3      for low, up in ranges: 
     9   1000000    1180737.0       1.2      7.3          low_pre_b_i = bisect.bisect_left(b1,low)
    10   1000000     608838.0       0.6      3.7          lo = blen[low_pre_b_i-1]
    11   1000000     490782.0       0.5      3.0          hi = blen[low_pre_b_i]
    12   1000000    2064953.0       2.1     12.7          l = bisect.bisect_left(a, low, lo=lo, hi=hi)
    13   1000000    1212568.0       1.2      7.5          high_pre_b_i = bisect.bisect_left(b1,up)
    14   1000000     606433.0       0.6      3.7          lo = blen[high_pre_b_i-1]
    15   1000000     492544.0       0.5      3.0          hi = blen[high_pre_b_i]
    16   1000000     460683.0       0.5      2.8          if l > lo:
    17        54        103.0       1.9      0.0              res.append(bisect.bisect_right(a, up, lo=l, hi=hi)-l)
    18                                                   else:
    19    999946    2132459.0       2.1     13.1              res.append(bisect.bisect_right(a, up, lo=lo, hi=hi)-l)
    20                                                   
    21         1          1.0       1.0      0.0      return res
```

Comment: I don’t have a computer for now. But I am pretty sure that  we cannot use numpy for this OJ question. Not sure about numba or cython part as I don’t know how to write any of these. The accept rate of this question is less than 1%, and OJ has the same accept condition for all programming language submissions (256 MB memory, 1000 ms). Theoretically, all programming languages should be able to pass. But for this one, sorting a ten million size list will cost at least 8 secs. So, I guess Python version is impossible to pass this question.

Comment: If you could write a C++ version which is 20 times faster than the Python version (no need for 100 times), then the answer will be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly faster approach would be to use list comprehension. In order to speed things up a bit in specific cases (often tested by online judges), I also used `set(ranges)` in case your ranges have repetitions but this can be deleted in case you know that there are few to no repetitions.

Here is the code bit:

```
import random

# generate random data that looks like yours
a = [random.randint(0, 30) for i in range(1000)]
ranges = [(random.randint(0, 20), random.randint(10, 30)) for i in range(1000)]

# using dictionary (your code)
def old_count(a, ranges):

    d = {}

    for i in range(len(ranges)):
        d[i] = 0

    for v in a:
        for i, (l, u) in enumerate(ranges):
            if l <= v <= u:
                d[i] += 1

    return d.values()

# using list comprehension (new code)
def count(a, ranges):
    return [((i, j), sum([i<=x<=j for x in a])) for (i, j) in set(ranges)]
```

Time-wise results are as such on my laptop:

```
# using dictionary (your code)

# for 1000 items in a and 1000 ranges
%timeit old_count(a, ranges)
# > 155 ms ± 1.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# for 10000 items in a and 10000 ranges
%timeit count(a, ranges)
# > 19.4 s ± 1.91 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
# using list comprehension (new code)

# for 1000 items in a and 1000 ranges
%timeit count(a, ranges)
# > 39.9 ms ± 1.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# for 10000 items in a and 10000 ranges
%timeit count(a, ranges)
# > 593 ms ± 112 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

There are probably faster/better solutions though.

A couple of things could be improved, I'll just name a few but there may be others:

- there may be duplicates in `a` as well
- some ranges may contain other ranges which renders checking some ranges unnecessary
- if the list of ranges is ordered, then it's not worth checking all of them

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's indeed faster in some cases than my solution, but the using of `set(ranges)` will change the order and the length of the result, which will result in wrong answer. Even if there may be duplicates in `a` as well, the number of duplicates is still need to be counted. The `ranges` are not ordered as far as I know.

Comment: True! While you could reorder your ranges afterwards, it's worth noting that the answer is still faster if you iterate over all ranges using `return [sum([i<=x<=j for x in a]) for (i, j) in ranges]` in the `count()` function! Perhaps is that enough to not encounter a TLE error?

Comment: Unfortunately no, still a TLE error. Because the OJ I used doesn't give a hint on which test example encountered a TLE error, I am not really sure if this is or not an improvement.

Comment: Timing it shows it is, but another important thing is: are the ranges ordered?

Comment: No, according to the given test example, there are not.

Comment: I will try to write a C++ version to see if the language matters.

Comment: This method is actually slower than the `bisect` method after test.

Comment: Didn't test that it tbh as you mentioned you had written the second bit of your code because using the `bisect` method with `sort` was too slow...